# Where to get poi final jar for xssf?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have downloaded poi -3.14 jar from Maven repository but it was having all packages for hssf where I need xssf for xlsx format. Where should I download xssf jar.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml

Comment: I already did that but it was not having xssf folder.

Comment: that jar does have the xssf folder. it is under `org\apache\poi`

Answer (score 5):

If you download POI from the apache site, you will get all the necessary dependencies in a single zip file.

https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

try these links : there are:) plethora of siltes google it
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoiooxml35beta5jar.htm
http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html